# How are qubits better than classical bit if they collapse to a classical state after measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

Classical computers store information in bits, which can either be $0$ or $1$, but, in a quantum computer, the qubit can store $0$, $1$ or a state that is the superposition of these two states. Now, when we make a "measurement" (to determine the state of qubit), it changes the state of the qubit, collapsing it from its superposition of $0$ and $1$ to the specific state consistent with the measurement result.

If from a measurement of a qubit we obtain only a single bit of information ($0$ or $1$, because the qubit collapses to either of the states), then, how is a qubit better than a classical bit? Since ultimately we are only able to get either $0$ or $1$ from either classical or quantum bit.

If you can explain with an example, it may be helpful.

Comment: The first chapter of [my PhD thesis](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~martinisgroup/theses/Sank2014.pdf) may help a bit.

Answer (score 11):

You are right that there's not much you can do with a single qubit. However it doesn't take many before you can do things that can't be done with classical bits. Here are a few illustrative examples.

### Communication

Imagine I make this offer to you and a friend of yours: I will give you each a classical bit, and then you will each give me a classical bit. If the XOR of the bits you give me is equal to the AND of the bits I gave you, you win.

You're allowed to come up with any strategy you want with your friend, but once I give you the bits, you can no longer communicate.

Well it is easy to show that the best you and your friend can hope to achieve is a 3/4 probability of winning. You just take the average over all deterministic strategies.

On the other hand, if only you and your friend each had **one qubit**, the combined state of which was $$\frac{\left| 00 \right> + \left| 11 \right>}{\sqrt{2}},$$ then you could win with probability [$\approx 0.85$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%5E2%28pi%2F8%29).

What I've just described is called the [CHSH game](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0404076). You can also come up with games where classically you can only win with some probability, but quantumly you can win with certainty.

### Computation

Let's say you have a problem where you know how to check if a solution is valid, but you don't know how to come up with a solution. The class of problems for which this is the case is called [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).

If you know a solution takes at most $n$ bits to encode, that means there are $2^n$ possible solutions. If you have $n$ qubits, you can put them in an equal superposition of all $n$-bit strings.

Now you can't exactly "check all strings to find a solution" all in one go, but there is something you can do.

When all strings are in an equal superposition, measuring your qubits will give you a completely random string. However, if you can make a circuit which verifies if a given string is a solution, then you can "[amplify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amplitude_amplification)" the probability that your measurement gives you a solution.

After $\mathcal{O} \left( \sqrt{2^n} \right)$ iterations of the amplitude amplification process, measuring your qubits will give you a solution.

Notice that this works for **any** problem as long as you can verify an answer. If we didn't have qubits, the "check all $n$-bit strings" approach would take $\mathcal{O} \left( 2^n \right)$ checks.

Comment: Just a little nitpicking: NP-complete is a specific class, where checking a solution has polynomial time-complexity, while finding one has exponential time-complexity (for all we know!) - and there are often approaches that are better than trying every single candidate solution, but they are still exponential. However, there are other complexity classes, where checking a solution is significantly faster than finding one - so this applies to all of these.

Comment: @kansi Yes, you save all measurements until the end, otherwise you collapse the state.

Comment: in the computation section: if you make a measurement then the "n" qubits will collapse into the state that u observed.
So the next time u make a measurement u know wat to expect, because the measurement u just made collapsed the qubits into one of the states and this is wat u would observe the next time.
So how would u get to the answer if u didnt get the right string, the first time?

Comment: @kansi The amplitude amplification process doesn't require measurements. Only at the very end do you measure to get your answer.

Comment: @AlexL first of all Thanx for replies :) ...
u said: "On the other hand, if only you and your friend each had one qubit ..." i think u are talking about entanglement, can u elaborate on that.

Comment: @kansi Yes, I was talking about entanglement. The two qubits are in the state $\frac{\left| 00 \right> + \left| 11 \right>}{\sqrt{2}}$, so if you measure 0 your friend will measure 0. To get to 0.85 probability of winning you have to each measure your qubits in a basis which depends on your own input. I don't know how to explain this intuitively, but the math shows that doing this lets you correlate your answers slightly better than classically.

Comment: @AlexL Clear and fun, +1. Interesting webpage too, been checking it out. BTW [this recent](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206492/quantum-and-classical-scaling-of-memory) post may interest you.

Answer (score -3):

Some calculations are too large for conventional (classical) computational capacity. These problems are classified as BQP, or bounded-error quantum polynomial time. The best way to formulate the question is "what is the use of quantum computing?", and that's where a qubit becomes useful.